# wbemtest doesn't show certain data after executing a query

Tags: wmi, wql

I have BitLocker enabled on my machine and I want to use the wbemtest.exe utility to view properties about the Bitlocker data.

According to the properties section at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), some of the data that I want to retrieve are DeviceID, DriveLetter, PersistentVolumeID, and ProtectionStatus.

However, when I execute the query

```
SELECT * from Win32_EncryptableVolume
```

using wbemtest.exe, only one object gets returned, and that is BitLocker DeviceID. I also want this query to return the DriveLetter and the other properties. What do I do to retrieve these? The data should be there, because my C# app using System.Management is able to get data on the other properties without any trouble (by assigning the return value of a ManagementClass GetInstances() method to a a ManagementObjectCollection.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am able to view the data I need quite simply by using the [WMI Code Creator utility.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572&ei=3lMeUqD1J8XRigKjqIHIDw&usg=AFQjCNFyVDExef24wxkRuJjZfo-tuDTpww&sig2=8idD38WMmODS7SvUWMS4Bw&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cGE)

I found this information on [windows-noob](http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/4095-how-can-i-determine-if-the-drive-is-encrypted-protected-or-not-during-a-bitlocker-task-sequence-in-winpe/)